# Find a basis $B$ such that the matrix of the linear map $f$ is in its Jordan form.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Show that a basis $v = (v_1, v_2, v_3)$ exists with respect to which $f$ has the mapping
matrix

$B= \begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 1 \\
   0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}$
and provide such a basis. You can use $v_1$ and $v_2$ from that you find in previous question.

In the previous part of the question it made me find a $v_1=(-1,2,1)$ and a $v_2$ in form of
$(-c,1+2c,c)$ through another mapping matrix
$ A= \begin{pmatrix} 2& −1& 3 \\
−1& 3& −5 \\
−1& 1& −2 \end{pmatrix}$

as I understand it the matrix $B$ seems to be in Jordan Form, trying to learn Jordan form now.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: You have not defined what $f$ is ? Is it supposed to be $A$ ???